# Cassandra: Streaming error - Compressed lengths mismatch

Tags: cassandra

I am restoring a snapshot in Cassandra using sstableloader. The sstable loading process fails for some of the nodes in the cluster with error

Error at sstableloader command:

```
Streaming to the following hosts failed:
[/10.x.x.x, /10.x.x.x, /10.x.x.x]
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.load(BulkLoader.java:98)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:48)
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
```

Error in logs for one the failed node:

```
 [Stream #bac90a-32] Streaming error occurred on session with peer 10.x.x.x
java.io.IOException: Compressed lengths mismatch
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor.uncompress(LZ4Compressor.java:147) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.compress.CompressedInputStream.decompress(CompressedInputStream.java:163) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.compress.CompressedInputStream.decompressNextChunk(CompressedInputStream.java:109) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.compress.CompressedInputStream.read(CompressedInputStream.java:121) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
```

What can be the possible cause of length mismatch?

Answer (score 1):

This generally indicates that the sstable that was streamed to the node was corrupted.  You could try running `nodetool scrub` on the source node and see if any corruption is identified by reviewing the scrub output in `system.log`.  Once you have fixed the source corruption, you could try taking the snapshot and loading it using sstableloader again.

You could also try to identify which sstable from the snapshot is corrupted by trying to run `sstabledump` on each table. If you get the same error when running sstabledump, you know you have found the corrupted file.  You could delete that file and try to load the rest of them.